# Not receiving messages between two IOS devices using Socket.io

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to create a chat app on IOS devices using Socket.io.
 Here the problem... when I emit a message from the IOS app to a socket I receive it on Node but the users from the IOS App subscribed to this socket not. If I do the emit to this socket from Node all users subscribed receive it but if the emit comes out from the app the users of the app do not receive it.

**Node:**

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('4-1status', function (from, msg) {
    console.log('receive it');
  });
});
```

**IOS:**

 Init SocketClient and sockets.

```
Constants.SocketClient = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: Constants.baseUrlSocket)!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
        Constants.SocketClient.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
            print("socket connected")
        }
Constants.SocketClient.on("4-1status") {[weak self] dataArray, ack in
                print("Recive")
                self?.statusChangeDelegate?.statusChange(values: dataArray[0] as! NSDictionary)
            }

Constants.SocketClient.connect()
```

Emit message to socket:

```
Constants.SocketClient.emit("4-1status", ["id": Constants.me.id, "status": "0"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to send the info through a broadcast in the server and then send it to a specific socket.